# How to merge array of object and another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, functional-programming

I have got two arrays and  array 2 will be merge array 1 . I am using concat , but I can not find any solution .

here is array 1 :

```
     let array1 = [{
            label: "OA deal activities",
            content: [{
                    label: "Create OA deals",
                },

                {
                    label: "Update OA deal",
                },

                {
                    label: "OA deals",

                },

            ]
        }]
```

Here is array 2 of objects :

```
let array2 =    [

        {
            label: "OA deal request",
            content: [{
                    label: 'OA Deal request List',
                },
                {
                    label: "View oadeal request",
                },
                {
                    label: "Update OA deal request",
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I want to marge array2 content properyt with array 1 content. my output would be like this format

```
  [{
        label: "OA deal activities",
        content: [{
                label: "Create OA deals",
            },

            {
                label: "Update OA deal",
            },

            {
                label: "OA deals",

            },{
                    label: 'OA Deal request List',
                },
                {
                    label: "View oadeal request",
                },
                {
                    label: "Update OA deal request",
                },

        ]
    }]
```

I am using concat javascript method , but can not find perfect solution.

```
let data = array1[0].content.concat(array2[0].content)
```

Comment: So how did you do it? Can you show that code?

Comment: array1.concat(array2)

Comment: u have nested array , iterate and push

Comment: Your inputs don't really make sense with your expected output. For example, there is no reference to "Deposit" in your result. Could you maybe simplify your example data and make sure the inputs match the outputs? That would help answer the question properly. Also, please include in your question the code you've tried thus far as that'll help you get better answers.

Comment: let data = array1[0].content.concat(array2[0].content)

Comment: @xdeepakv can you give me the solution

Comment: why    label: "OA deal request" is not there in your desired output?

Comment: I just want to marge array 2 content with array 1

Comment: see answer, i dont like it! u should try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like `array1[0].content = array1[0].content.concat(array2[0].content)` should work

but for ES6 you can also do

`array1[0].content = [...array1[0].content, ...array2[0].content]`

if you have multiple items in array one and array2, you could do this too (as long as their length matches)

```js
array1.forEach(function(a, i){a.content = a.content.concat(array2[i].content)
```

ES6 version:

```js
array1.forEach((a, i) => {a.content = [...a.content, ...array2[i].content]})
```

Comment: I want to merge array 2 content property with array1

Comment: how is it different from this solution though?

Comment: sorry got an answer but , can you do without using [0] , I mean I want to do dynamically

Answer (score 1):

```
const mergedArray = [...array1[0].content, ...array2[0].content]
array1[0].content = mergedArray
```

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log({label: array1[0].label, content : [...array1[0].content, ...array2[1].content]})
```

```js
let array1 = [
  {
    label: "OA deal activities",
    content: [
      { label: "Create OA deals" },
      { label: "Update OA deal" },
      { label: "OA deals" }
    ]
  }
];

let array2 = [
  {
    label: "Deposit",
    content: [{ label: "Deposits" }, { label: "Deposit approval" }]
  },
  {
    label: "OA deal activities",
    content: [
      { label: "OA Deal request List" },
      { label: "View oadeal request" },
      { label: "Update OA deal request" }
    ]
  }
];

console.log({
  label: array1[0].label,
  content: [...array1[0].content, ...array2[1].content]
});
// For complex array of array
const flatten = (arr, depth = 1) =>
  arr.reduce(
    (a, v) =>
      a.concat(depth > 1 && Array.isArray(v) ? flatten(v, depth - 1) : v),
    []
  );
const result2 = {
  ...array1[0],
  content: flatten(
    array1.map(x => x.content).concat(array2.map(x => x.content))
  )
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(result2, null, 2));
```